# Kivy Label not updating after a change

Tags: python, kivy, label

a.py

```py
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from enum import Enum
from enum import auto
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import threading

class menu(Enum):
    Espresso = (0)
    Latte = (1)
    Sahlep = (2)
    TurkKahvesi = (3)
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id


class Test(Screen):
    pass

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class Third(Screen):
    pass


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Tabs(TabbedPanel):
    pass

class Labs():
    pass

class CountSigns(StackLayout):
    my_text = 0
    count = 0

    def on_button_click_plus(self):
        print("Button clicked plus")
        self.count += 1
        self.my_text = str(self.count)
        print(self.my_text)

        return self.my_text
    def on_button_click_minus(self):
        print("Button clicked minus")
        self.my_text = str(self.count)

        if self.count > 0:
            self.count -= 1

        else:
            pass

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        value = str(self.my_text)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        b = Button(text='latte', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 100))
        self.add_widget(b)
        b.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.on_button_click_plus())


        lab = Label(text= str(self.my_text), color= (1, .5, 1, 1), size=(50, 100), size_hint=(None, None))
        self.add_widget(lab)


        btn1 = Button(text='-', size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 100))
        btn1.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.on_button_click_minus())
        self.add_widget(btn1)




class WidgetsExample(CountSigns):
    value = CountSigns.my_text

class WidgetsExample2(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(WidgetsExample2,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.top_grid = GridLayout() # Widget above main widget to hold all text and input boxes.
        self.cols = 2 # no.of columns


kv = Builder.load_file("b.kv")


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

b.kv

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    Third:


<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols:2


        Button:
            text: "New Order"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "third"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


<Third>:
    name: "third"
    Tabs:
        do_default_tab: False

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Hot Drinks'
            CountSigns:
```

So when I run this code, the my_text in 'lab' ia not updating in the GUI. However the prints show that my_text actually changes. How can I make it so that the label updates. I basically want the button itself to make the value go up and the minus button to make the value go down. It did work when my code was in the kv file however since I needed to store the values I decided I needed to define these values in the python file.

Answer (score 0):

you update your 'self.my_text' but you don't actually update your Label when you are clicking on '-' or '+'

```
class CountSigns(StackLayout):
    my_text = 0
    count = 0
    
    lab = Label(text="", color=(1, .5, 1, 1), size=(50, 100), size_hint=(None, None))

    def on_button_click_plus(self):
        print("Button clicked plus")
        
        self.count += 1
        self.my_text = str(self.count)
        self.lab.text = str(self.my_text)

        return self.my_text

    def on_button_click_minus(self):
        print("Button clicked minus")

        self.my_text = str(self.count)
        self.lab.text = str(self.my_text)

        if self.count > 0:
            self.count -= 1

        else:
            pass

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        value = str(self.my_text)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        b = Button(text='latte', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 100))
        self.add_widget(b)
        b.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.on_button_click_plus())


        self.lab.text = str(self.my_text)
        self.add_widget(self.lab)


        btn1 = Button(text='-', size_hint=(None, None), size=(50, 100))
        btn1.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.on_button_click_minus())
        self.add_widget(btn1)
```

You could define your Label as a Class attribute so you can access/update it when you need to.

edit:
You could also work like you used to; configure your labels/buttons in the .kv file. But then you would have to work with ids. Maybe that's also an option to keep your .py file 'clean' in case you would add a lot of Widgets.

EDIT2 (with widgets in the .kv file):

**.py**

```
class CountSigns(StackLayout):
    my_text = 0
    count = 0

    def on_button_click_plus(self):
        print("Button clicked plus")

        self.count += 1
        self.my_text = str(self.count)
        self.ids['label_id'].text = str(self.my_text)

        return self.my_text

    def on_button_click_minus(self):
        print("Button clicked minus")

        if self.count > 0:
            self.count -= 1
        else:
            pass

        self.my_text = str(self.count)
        self.ids['label_id'].text = str(self.my_text)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        value = str(self.my_text)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

**.kv**

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    Third:


<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols:2


        Button:
            text: "New Order"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "third"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"


<CountSigns>:
    plus_sign: plus_sign
    label_id: label_id
    min_sign: min_sign

    Button:
        id: plus_sign
        text: 'latte'
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (100, 100)
        on_press:
            root.on_button_click_plus()

    Label:
        id: label_id
        text: str(root.my_text)
        color: (1, .5, 1, 1)
        size: (50, 100)
        size_hint: (None, None)

    Button:
        id: min_sign
        text: '-'
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (50, 100)
        on_press:
            root.on_button_click_minus()



<Third>:
    name: "third"
    Tabs:
        do_default_tab: False

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Hot Drinks'
            CountSigns:
```

ps: when you decrement in your 'on_button_click_minus', decrement first, then update the Label. Right now you click and nothing happens because you decrement after you update the Label.

Comment: The thing is I want the label between the 2 buttons , I dunno how I exactly do that if I seperate it

Comment: Where can I look to check how the ID's work?

Comment: Check the latest edit, that should work. Just google a lot about kivy ids. And search for some code examples. The more you search the more you will the hang of it.

Comment: My question is like how do I reach the stuff thats inside the buttons in the kv like the text, cause I want to make a string with the name and the count in the KV file.

Comment: Make use of the 'id' attribute like in the example I gave you. And then in your Python file, use 'self.ids['id_of_your_widget'] to access it. I don't think you can really concatenate strings and such in the .kv file itself, that should be done in the .py I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
<CountSigns>:
    drink: drink
    plus_sign: plus_sign
    label_id: label_id
    min_sign: min_sign

    Label:
        id: drink
        text: 'coffee'
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (100, 100)
    Button:
        id: plus_sign
        text: '+'
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (50, 100)
        on_press:
            root.on_button_click_plus()

    Label:
        id: label_id
        text: str(root.my_text)
        color: (1, .5, 1, 1)
        size: (50, 100)
        size_hint: (None, None)

    Button:
        id: min_sign
        text: '-'
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (50, 100)
        on_press:
            root.on_button_click_minus()




<StackLayoutExample>
    CountSigns:
    CountSigns:
        root.ids.drink.text: 'peach'
    CountSigns:
```

How can I use ids in the kv file I tried changing the label text with         root.ids.drink.text: 'peach' but that didnt work. Is  it possible to achieve this?